# Change data between few router-view

Tags: vue.js

I have two  components, and can't pass data from one to another component

at first router-view have

```
            data() {
            return {
                mode: true,
            }
        },
<input type="checkbox" class="switch-mode" v-model="mode" @change="$root.$emit('switch-mode', mode)">
```

and other is

```
            data() {
        return {
            filter: {
                mode: false,
                order: 'DESC'
            },
        }
    },
    mounted() {
    this.$root.$on('switch-mode', function (EventGrid) {
    console.log('Grid mode is '+EventGrid); //this works it return true,false
    this.filter.mode = EventGrid; // not working this.filter is undefined"
        })
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because your function doesn't know what `this` is, you should explicitly tell it to use your component:

```
mounted() {
  this.$root.$on(
    'switch-mode', 
    (function (EventGrid) { ... }).bind(this)
  )
}
```

Or, more effectively and modern, use an arrow function:

```
mounted() {
  this.$root.$on('switch-mode', (EventGrid) => { ... })
}
```